# How to debug an application (exe) freeze and crash?

Tags: disassembly, debugging

I have an app (and I don't know the source code), that freeze and crash everytime it loses focus (but the music continue). I've tried to debug it using windbg but it doesn't change anything, and I don't know how to log the freeze/crash properly.

How can i know what happened ? In term of assembly instructions or memory ?

CONTEXT :

- Graphic App (Nvidia drivers)
- 32 BIT APP created on windows 7
- Crash on windows 7 32 bit
- Debugging on windows 10 64 bit
- Not related to the hardware, crash on different computer the same way
- Unfocus the app = Frozen, then "unresponding", nothing else. It crashes when windows send a report
- Cannot crash when executed by a debugger, it only froze (Even the process manager cannot close the app)

UPDATE :
Procdump + Windbg analysis (The app didn't crashed under procdump, it only crashed after stopping procdump process)

```
ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

COMMENT:  
*** procdump.exe  -e -ma -t -w "name.exe"
*** Process termination

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001f64

PROCESS_NAME:  name.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
1d63fdb0 77131030     000002e4 06ff3150 00000010 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
1d63ff70 76abfa29     00b39e00 76abfa10 1d63ffdc ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x2a0
1d63ff80 771475f4     00b39e00 26f0b456 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
1d63ffdc 771475c4     ffffffff 77167350 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
1d63ffec 00000000     77130d90 00b39e00 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


SYMBOL_NAME:  ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+c

MODULE_NAME: ntdll

IMAGE_NAME:  ntdll.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_ntdll.dll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.19041.662

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {bb9287bd-f940-f1d0-c927-6d6da8a242a3}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Update 2 :
It seems that only the graphic content freeze. The sounds is okay

Update 3 :
Freeze when whole computer when fullscreen. Cannot access to any other window, WIN key show taskbar but nothing happen when trying to switch app even with WIN+TAB

Update 4 :
Seems to be related to Nvidia drivers

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! The app crashes on Windows 7 or it was written for Windows 7 and crashes when you run it on, say, Windows 10? The Windows you run it on is a 32-bit or 64-bit one? You give far too little contextual information to help you further. In general you could attempt to start it via WinDbg and hope for the crash to be replicated this way. Once it crashes you'd see a call stack of what happened. Alternatively `procdump` can be used for a similar effect.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It was written on windows 7,  and I run the app on a 64bit computer. But it crashes on windows 7 32bit too so, I don't really know, I guess the app don't handle the "unfocus" event properly or something. With WinDbg, the game freeze and stay frozen, it won't crash and it won't close even if I spam the "close window" button. I can't even move the process window. When I hit "Stop debugging" (only way to stop the process without closing WinDbg) it doesn't print anything.. I'll try with procdump.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it but I really don't know how and why.
It was nvidia drivers, changing gpu solved the error.
With nvidia gpu, adding it to the program list solved it.
Whatever, I wonder how we can fix that without user interaction